# "He go to school directly". Why this sentence is wrong?

Tags: grammar

> "He go to school directly"

I heard this sentence from someone and he told me that it's wrong. But I don't know why it is wrong. I need full explanation with examples which get me to understand this sentence.

Comment: Can you give some context? What is meant with *directly* - is that about time or place?

Comment: @JanDoggen, It is about place.

Comment: **Why is** that sentence wrong? Because:  “I go.  You go.  **He goes**, she goes, it goes.  We go.  They go.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **directly** in the sense "without taking any detours" the usual way would be this:

> He goes directly to school.

Answer (score 0):

Should be probably like this.

> He **goes** to school directly.

Alternatively like this.

> He **will** go to school directly.

Comment: We tend not to name children "He".  I don't think that addendum really helps OP.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You call your offspring your way, I call mine my way. I'm sure there's a language where that name makes perfect sense (and/or may be a nickname). But the amendment I made was purely theoretical aiming at providing as complete answer as possible. Help to OP was provided in the first two suggestions. If you feel it confuses and deteriorates the quality/clarity of the reply, feel free to edit. I mind not.   :)

Comment: I do think it is more likely to confuse than to help, though I do understand how you were working backwards from the syntax to confer "namehood" on "He".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Did you downvote? How come?

Comment: Yes I did, but I got a phone call and forgot to say why. Sorry. I  myself really dislike unexplained downvotes.   The placement of **directly** there is not  idiomatic.